# How to compile all code including dependencies to LLVM IR?

Tags: rust, llvm, static-linking

I have a Rust crate `A` that depends on another Rust crate `B`; both of them are STD-clean (i.e. both use `#![no_std]`) and there are no other dependencies. I would like to get my hands on the LLVM IR of all the code needed to statically link it together with `lld`.

To get the LLVM IR from just `A`, I am currently passing `--emit=llvm-ir` to `cargo rustc`. This results in `target/debug/deps/A-someKindOfHash.ll` which I can then consume -- in my case, by using Clang to link it with some C code that calls (non-mangled) Rust functions.

However, that `.ll` file doesn't contain all transitive dependencies, so as soon as `A` actually starts using functions from `B`, this breaks down.

How do I tell Cargo to create LLVM IR from all dependencies and put them somewhere under `target/`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust: Including dependenies in LLVM Bitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042049/rust-including-dependenies-in-llvm-bitcode) (bitcode is the binary form of the IR)