# How to manually provide core::panicking::panic* to lld?

Tags: rust, linker, llvm, rust-no-std

I am compiling the Rust code of an rlib to LLVM IR, and then using Clang to compile & link it with a C program. This works until my code contains panics, at which point I get linker errors:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: core::panicking::panic_bounds_check::hc3a71010bf41c72d
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(run)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(run)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(run)
>>> referenced 11 more times

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: core::panicking::panic::hd695e3b1d0dd4ef4
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(run)
clang: error: ld.lld command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried two things to mitigate this:

1. I have added a `panic_handler` to my library:

   ```
   use core::panic::PanicInfo;

   #[panic_handler]
   pub extern fn panic(_: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
       loop{}
   }
   ```
2. I have set the `panic` mode to `abort` in my `Cargo.toml`:

   ```
   [profile.release]
   panic = "abort"
   ```

Neither on its own, nor combined, solves the issue.

## Further details

In the comments, @Solomon Ucko requested more details on the whole compilation pipeline. As I wrote in the tags, this is with `no_std`; also, the compilation target is [MOS 6502](https://llvm-mos.org/wiki/Welcome). This is the full list of commands to compile and (try to) link:

```
llvm-mos/bin/clang --config llvm-mos-sdk/build/commodore/64.cfg \
    -O2 -c \
    -o _build/main.c.o \
    src/main.c
cargo rustc --release -- \
    -C debuginfo=0 -C opt-level=1 --emit=llvm-ir
llvm-mos/bin/clang --config llvm-mos-sdk/build/commodore/64.cfg \
    -O2 \
    -o _build/charset.prg \
    _build/main.c.o \
    target/release/deps/chip8_c64-e21ff59526dd729a.ll
```

Comment: What commands are you currently running to compile and link the Rust code? Also, are you using `no_std`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69048758/477476), I worked around this by passing `-Z build-std` to Cargo, thereby getting the LLVM IR from Rust's `core` library, and linking it in.

But then I realized I can do one better, and avoid the long compilation time imposed by `-Z std`, by just taking the definitions of
`core::panicking::panic_bounds_check` and `core::panicking::panic` from these IR files, simplifying their body, and adding them to a hand-written `panic.ll` file:

```
%"panic::location::Location" = type { { [0 x i8]*, i64 }, i32, i32 }

; core::panicking::panic
; Function Attrs: cold noinline noreturn nounwind nonlazybind
define void @_ZN4core9panicking5panic17hd695e3b1d0dd4ef4E([0 x i8]* noalias nonnull readonly align 1 %expr.0, i64 %expr.1, %"panic::location::Location"* noalias readonly align 8 dereferenceable(24) %0) unnamed_addr #22 {
start:
  unreachable
}

; core::panicking::panic_bounds_check
; Function Attrs: cold noinline noreturn nounwind nonlazybind
define void @_ZN4core9panicking18panic_bounds_check17hc3a71010bf41c72dE(i64 %0, i64 %1, %"panic::location::Location"* noalias readonly align 8 dereferenceable(24) %2) unnamed_addr #22 {
start:
  unreachable
}
```

TBH I'm not sure how robust that is (maybe they should loop by branchin to `start` before `unreachable?), but at least it got me to a fully linked and runnable program.

Comment: It depends how sound you want your solution to be, really. `unreachable` or infinite-loop-to-start are both Undefined Behavior if reached in LLVM -- following C semantics with regards to loops without side-effects. I'm not sure about the best way to get LLVM to emit `ud2` or similar trap instruction.